# Dynamically created collapsible-set in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Okay, once i see the answer to this, I will feel stupid.  I'm certain of that.

I've created this exactly the way I want to before, but I am refactoring my code for a new version right now.  I am trying to dynamically create collapsible sets in jQuery Mobile, but my html does not render right.

```
  <div data-role="header">
        <h2>Playground</h2>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div data-role="button" id="addprimary" data-inline="true">Add 5</div>
        <div data-role="collapsible">             
            <h4>Collapsible</h4> 
            <form id="makecollapsible">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Please, no applause</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$('#addprimary').on('click', function () {
    Markup.Collapsible();
});

var Markup = new Object();


Markup.Collapsible = function () {

$('#makecollapsible')
.append($('<div>')
    .attr({ 'data-role': 'collapsible-set', 'id': 'primary' })
 );
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    ($('<div>')
         .attr({ 'data-role': 'collapsible', 'data-content-theme': 'c', 
              'data-collapsed': 'true' })
         .html('<h4>' + i +'</h4>'))
    .appendTo('#primary');
   }
}
</script>
```

Could somebody please take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/c2jLY/ and tell me what I have wrong?  My `<div>`s with `data-role='collapsible'` are not rendering as collapsibles, which is also having an effect on the HTML I am trying to put in them later on.

Help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You should definitely still post your code in the question.

Comment: Can you describe what you are seeing or what you think is wrong?  If I look at your fiddle, click the "Add 5" button, then click the Collapsible element, it opens with your content inside.  I would appear everything is working to me.  What do you expect to see?

Comment: @BradleyBossard he wants this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/zyEuB/ :)

Comment: @BradleyBossard I needed the enhanced jQueryMobile DOM Elements, not just the HTML itself. Omar's solution works exactly as I needed it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside `Markup.Collapsible` function and at the end of it, add the below. For **collapsible-set**, you need to tell jQM that you're enhancing a `.collapsibleset()` and combine it with `.trigger('create')`.

```
$('#makecollapsible').collapsibleset().trigger('create');
```

> [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/zyEuB/)

---

I forgot to mention that when appending items dynamically, call enhancement methods on parent element; doing so, will enhance children elements. Thus, you don't need to use `.collapsible().trigger('create')` for each collapsible appended.

Answer (score 0):

what i show here is a simple one but working:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
//dynamically make 10 collapsible items and append them to the collapsible-set
var jj = "SUPER item added..";

$('[data-role="content"]').append('<div id="set" data-role="collapsible-set"></div>');
var count;
 for (count=0; count < 10; count++) {  // div id should be from id='c0' to 'c9'
  $("#set").append('<div id="c' + count + '" data-role="collapsible">');
  $("#c" + count.toString()).append('<h3>Adding element_' + count +'</h3>');
  $("#c" + count.toString()).append(jj + 'count ' + count + '</div>');

 }

// either one is tested working below:
//  $('[data-role="content"]').trigger('create');
  $( "#set" ).collapsibleset( "refresh" );

</script>
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <!------------------------page 1 ListView template-->
  <div data-role="page"  id="page01">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">   
   <h2>-- DEMO -- &nbsp;&nbsp;</h2>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content"  id="content">
  
    </div>
</body>
```